# FormData jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, forms

```
var f = '\
  <form id="myForm" name="myForm">\
    <div>\
      <label for="username">Enter name:</label>\
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username">\
    </div>\
    <div>\
      <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>\
      <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc">\
    </div>\
    <div>\
      <label for="userfile">Upload file:</label>\
      <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile">\
    </div>\
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">\
  </form>\
';
document.write(f);

var test = document.getElementById('myForm');
console.log(test);
var form_data = new FormData(test);
```

I try to collect all data from all fields using FormData.
Why, why it doesn't work? 
Formdata is empty...

Comment: `form_data` is created way before user inputs something in.

Comment: I have updated the answer, seems like it's do the trick, check it out

Comment: well, i mean.... the inputs are empty...

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery method `.serializeArray()` for this, it's pretty easy, for example:

```
$('form').serializeArray();
```

This way you can collect all your input values, except files. To get files you can use something like `$('#userfile').prop('files');`.

Here is the working snippet:

```js
var f = '\
  <form id="myForm" name="myForm">\
    <div>\
      <label for="username">Enter name:</label>\
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username">\
    </div>\
    <div>\
      <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>\
      <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc">\
    </div>\
    <div>\
      <label for="userfile">Upload file:</label>\
      <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile">\
    </div>\
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit!" onclick="collectData()">\
</form>\
';

document.write(f);

function collectData() {
  var form_data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
  var file = $('#userfile').prop('files');
  form_data.push(file);
  console.log(form_data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP said *«I try to collect all data from all fields»*. Your solution is getting the values when the form is still empty.

Comment: With a `type="button"` and a `value="Get the form values"` (Instead of "submit"... Because it is not submitting at all...) It would be a correct answer.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, yes, but if to use `type="button"`, the form submits immediately and we don't see the `console.log`.

Comment: Nope. `<input type="button">` doesn't submit. `<input type="submit">` and `<button>Hello</button>` does. And `<button type="button">Hello</button>` doesn't.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, thanks for your correction, I didn't know about that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Good ;) Now I'm pretty sure OP will want to submit... For now, `form_data` is declared in `collectData()` and can only be used for the `console.log`... But that may be another question...

Comment: Commercial Suicide, можно вопрос в скайпе, пожалуйста. skype - stasmann

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий, 5-10 минут и я позвоню